# CSS - Div not taking up entire width

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

For some reason my html and css isn't taking up the entire width of the page, even though I set margin and padding to 0, and width to 100%. It's always worked before, but I have no idea why it isn't working this time. The only thing that has been implemented so far is the just the background and navbar. I have attached an image to demonstrate how it appears right now. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```css
    *{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       width: 100%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       font-family: sans-serif;
    }
 
    body{
       overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .container{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       background: #42455a;
    }

    .navbar ul{
       display: inline-flex;
       margin: 50px;
    }

    .navbar ul li{
       list-style: none;
       margin: 0px 20px;
       color: #b2b1b1;
       cursor: pointer;
    }

    .logo img{
       width: 30px;
       margin-top: -7px;
       margin-right: 48px;
    }

    .active{
       color: #19dafa !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <!-- CSS Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS File -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="check.css">

    <title>Webpage title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <!-- logo -->
                <li class="logo"><img src=""></li> 
                <li class="active">Home</li>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>Product</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap.css, which defines a `max-width: 540px` rule on any element with `class="container"` when the browser viewport width is wider than `576px`:

[image]

To fix this, use a different class name other than `container`, or extend the `.container` rule in your own stylesheet to set `max-width: none;`.

But, in my frank opinion, the best solution is to not use Bootstrap.css and to instead take responsibility for styling your own website. I feel Bootstrap has gotten bigger and bigger over the years it takes just as much effort to "learn Bootstrap" as it does to learn how to write one's own base common stylesheet.

Comment: `container-fluid` is built into Bootstrap ;)

Comment: @J.Titus Yeah, but I don't know the OP's intent. Bootstrap needs to die, imo. It took 12 years, but jQuery is now in-decline, I hope Bootstrap (and all the other "RAD, but not really" CSS toolkits follows suit.

Comment: Thank you guys very much, it worked. I spent too much time on this.